# Selecting features by attributes using ogr2ogr?

Tags: shapefile, sql, ogr, ogr2ogr, select-by-attribute

I am writing a shapefile after some processing; however, in the final step I need to do some selection by attributes from the the shapefile.

I am using the command in a shell with the aim of using it in a Python script when it works.

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -select * where ID="1" outfile.shp infile.shp
```

I am getting the error message:

```
FAILURE: 
Unable to open datasource `Downloads' with the following drivers.
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Is that really the exact message for that command?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You miss a minus sign before `where` and the `select` is not necessary, so it should be:

```
ogr2ogr -where ID="1" outfile.shp infile.shp
```

or if you have to do more complex query on your input data:

```
ogr2ogr -sql "SELECT * FROM infile WHERE ID='1'" outfile.shp infile.shp
```

If `ID` is a field of Integer type, substitute `ID='1'` with `ID=1`.

Notes:

1. If using GDAL < 2.3,`-f "ESRI Shapefile"` is not necessary because `"ESRI Shapefile"` is the `ogr2ogr` default output format; If using GDAL >= 2.3, the format is guessed from the extension.
2. it's convenient to skip `-select` and use directly the `-where` clause when you want to select all the fields.

Comment: Many thanks it works. I am using: ogr2ogr -where "ID='1'" output.shp input.shp

Comment: How can I use this code : ogr2ogr -sql "SELECT * FROM infile WHERE ID='1'" outfile.shp infile.shp" in python?

Comment: @ShiuliPervin you can use the statement in python by using `os.system('''ogr2ogr ... ''') `. be sure to `import os` at the top of your python script

Comment: @afalciano, for the statement `ogr2ogr -sql "SELECT * FROM infile WHERE ID='1'" outfile.shp infile.shp` instead of just ID=1 is there a way to provide a vector or a set of numbers instead, e.g. `ogr2ogr -sql "SELECT * FROM infile WHERE ID IN ['1','5','29']" outfile.shp infile.shp`?

Comment: @afalciano one other thing...instead of writing out another shp file, is there a way to just get the coordinates of the selected ID polygons?

Comment: @h.l.m **First question**: you have to type numbers as numbers, so your example should be `ogr2ogr -sql "SELECT * FROM infile WHERE ID IN [1,5,29]" outfile.shp infile.shp`
**Second question**: to get the coordinates of the selected geometry without creating another shp: `ogrinfo -sql "SELECT OGR_GEOMETRY FROM infile WHERE ID IN [1,5,29]" infile.shp`

Comment: When using the `-where` switch option, I needed to identify the value with single quotes instead of double quotes in order for it to work.

Comment: With GDAL 3.6 the list needs to be () not [], e.g., `ogr2ogr -sql "SELECT * FROM infile  WHERE OBJECTID IN (1,5,29)"`