# OGR2OGR and SQL: selecting 30 biggest places from a country?

Tags: sql, ogr2ogr, natural-earth

I use ogr2org to filter naturalearth [places.shp](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/ne_10m_populated_places.zip) :

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -where "ADM0NAME = 'India' AND POP_MAX > 500000" places.tmp.geo.json ne_10m_populated_places.shp
```

I would prefer to **select the 30 biggest places (via ORDER BY POP_MAX DESC LIMIT 30)**. In the [ORG SQL doc](http://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql.html#ogr_sql_order_by) recommands something such :

```
SELECT * FROM property WHERE class_code = 7 ORDER BY prop_value DESC
```

I tried both

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -where "ADM0NAME = 'India' ORDER BY POP_MAX LIMIT 1,30" places.tmp.geo.json ne_10m_populated_places.shp
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -sql "SELECT * FROM ne_10m_populated_places WHERE ADM0NAME = 'India' ORDER BY POP_MAX LIMIT 30" places.tmp.geo.json ne_10m_populated_places.shp
```

But it doesn't work. What does I do wrong ? How to query right ?

Comment: [This one](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77476/) helps a bit

Comment: This link http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp suggests the syntax for LIMIT has only one parameter (LIMIT 30 not LIMIT 1,30), also it mentions the TOP operator which may help (SELECT TOP 30 POP_MAX * FROM ne_10m_populated_places). It may be though that your input SQL does't support all SQL operators.

Comment: Limit in SQLite can take two parameters http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html. Then the first parameter means the same than using a separate OFFSET. Thus this query is selecting 30 cities beginning from the second biggests which was, according to the question, not the meaning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have GDAL/OGR 1.10 or later, use `-dialect SQLITE` for the [SQLite SQL dialect](http://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql_sqlite.html), which supports `ORDER BY POP_MAX DESC LIMIT 30` in SQL statements.

Answer (score 4):

'Limit' is not implemented with OGR2OGR . However, you can add and calculate a field with an integer on your 30 biggest places and filter on your new field.

this works :

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -sql "SELECT * FROM ne_10m_populated_places WHERE ADM0NAME = 'India' ORDER BY POP_MAX" places.tmp.geo.json ne_10m_populated_places.shp
```

with your new field :

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -sql "SELECT * FROM ne_10m_populated_places WHERE ADM0NAME = 'India' and my_new_integer_field < 31 ORDER BY POP_MAX" places.tmp.geo.json ne_10m_populated_places.shp
```

Comment: I'am very new to SQL, how could I add this new_integer_field ?

Comment: Wrong answer if compile with Sqlite support. By adding `-dialect SQLITE` the LIMIT keyword works...

Comment: This is a great workaround for versions before GDAL/OGR 1.10