# How to extract a shapefile with a SQL expression from a database of shapefiles using PyQGIS or OGR

Tags: python, pyqgis, ogr, ogr2ogr, extract

I have a shapefile `Water_Districts.shp` that consists of several water district polygons. I am trying to use the script below to 'extract' a specific polygon with the name `Cache La Poudre River` listed under the `NAME` column in the `Water_Districts.shp` attribute table. I have been using the python script below, but am not sure how to incorporate the SQL expression in the `-where` exception of the `ogr2ogr` command. I am getting the error: `FAILURE: SetAttributeFilter(NAME = Cache La Poudre River) on layer'Water_Districts' failed.`

```
import gdal
import subprocess

directory = r"F:\IrrigatedLands\FC_test\Water_Districts\Water_Districts.shp"
output_shp = r"F:\IrrigatedLands\FC_qgis\boundary.shp"

subprocess.call(["ogr2ogr", "-where", "NAME = Cache La Poudre River", output_shp, directory])
```

Comment: Check this out: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77476/ogr2ogr-selecting-features-by-attributes

Answer (score 1):

The following code below worked with no errors:

```
import gdal
import subprocess

directory = r"F:\IrrigatedLands\FC_test\Water_Districts\Water_Districts.shp"
output_shp = r"F:\IrrigatedLands\FC_qgis\boundary.shp"

subprocess.call(["ogr2ogr", "-where", "NAME = 'Cache La Poudre River'", output_shp, directory])
```