# Remove all polygons except the main one from GeoJSON / Shapefile

Tags: shapefile, gdal, polygon, geojson, ogr2ogr

I've got the [coastline of Canada](https://github.com/Microsoft/USBuildingFootprints/files/2216787/CC.zip) from OSM. For my work I only need the main landmass without any islands. Despite I was able to manually delete all the islands in JOSM / QGIS I need an automatic solution.

How to remove all polygons except the main one from a GeoJSON (or Shapefile) in commandline?

---

Even this simply doesn't work

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -dialect SQLITE -sql "SELECT * FROM Canada_1428125_AL2 order by ST_AREA(geometry) desc limit 1" out.geojson Canada_1428125_AL2.shp
```

because the multipolygon contains all islands. Is there any splitter function?

Answer (score 1):

Based on this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77476/ogr2ogr-selecting-features-by-attributes/77480#77480) to [Selecting features by attributes using ogr2ogr?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77476/ogr2ogr-selecting-features-by-attributes), you could order by by perimeter or surface enclosed by the line and take only the first row with `Limit 1`

example:

```
ogr2ogr -sql "SELECT * FROM infile order by ST_AREA(ST_MakePolygon(geom)) desc limit 1" outfile.shp infile.shp
```

ST_MakePolygon creates a polygon from your lines. If you have polygons do not use the ST_MakePolygon statement. I understood the coastline as lines, that's why I used the ST_MakePolygon function.

Comment: You can sort on-the-fly by using GDAL SQLite dialect and function ST_Area. Could you try to edit your answer and give a complete usage example?

Comment: Even this simply doesn't work

    ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -dialect SQLITE -sql "SELECT * FROM Canada_1428125_AL2 order by ST_AREA(geometry) desc limit 1" out.geojson Canada_1428125_AL2.shp

because the multipolygon contains all islands. Is there any splitter function?

Answer (score 1):

You must do it in two steps:

Explode the multipolygon
Use ogr2ogr with -explodecollections as documented in https://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -explodecollections exploded_polygons.shp Canada_1428125_AL2.shp
```

Select the biggest of the exploded polygons like you have tried

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -dialect SQLITE -sql "SELECT * FROM exploded_polygons order by ST_AREA(geometry) desc limit 1" out.geojson exploded_polygons.shp
```