# Error using SQL statement in ogr2ogr with Python string formatter

Tags: sql, ogr2ogr, python-3

I am iterating through a list of shapefiles and extracting subsets of each shapefile to save as a KML using ogr2ogr. How can I extract the subset based on multiple conditions while using string formatter to define the in/out files and conditions? I am following the answer from [Selecting features by attributes using ogr2ogr?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77476/selecting-features-by-attributes-using-ogr2ogr) in my attempt.

Using Python 3.7

This example with only one condition works without issue:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pathlib

## example dummy ids
id1 = np.linspace(start=1, stop=5, num=5, endpoint=True, dtype=int)
id2 = np.linspace(start=301, stop=302, num=2, endpoint=True, dtype=int)

outpath = pathlib.Path("working").resolve()
for ii in id1:
    command = (
        ' ogr2ogr -f "KML" "{outfile}" "{infile}" '
        ' -where "ID_1 = {my_id}" '
        ' -dsco NameField = "{name}" '
    )
    fout = 'test' + str(ii) + '.kml'
    fout = outpath / fout
    os.system(command.format(outfile=fout, infile='points.shp', my_id=ii, name='county'))
```

This example with multiple conditions using a SQL query returns an error:

```
for ii in id1:
    for jj in id2:
            command = (
                ' ogr2ogr -f "KML" "{outfile}" "{infile}" '
                ' -sql "SELECT * from {infile2} WHERE ID_1 = {my_id} AND ID_2 = {other_id}" '
                ' -dsco NameField = "{name}" '
            )
            print(command)
            fout = 'test' + str(ii) + '_' + str(jj) + '.kml'
            fout = outpath / fout
            os.system(command.format(
                outfile=fout,
                infile='points.shp',
                infile2=pathlib.Path('points.shp').stem,
                my_id=ii,
                other_id=jj,
                name='county')
            )
```

print statement returns:

```
ogr2ogr -f "KML" "{outfile}" "{infile}"  -sql "SELECT * from {infile2} WHERE ID_1 = {my_id} AND ID_2 = {other_id}"  -dsco NameField = "{name}"
```

And the error:

```
Warning 1: layer names ignored in combination with -sql.
ERROR 1: SQL Expression Parsing Error: syntax error, unexpected $undefined, expecting string or identifier. Occurred around :
SELECT * from points WHERE ID_1
              ^
```

Comment: Suggest you try `gdal.VectorTranslate` (pretty much identical to `ogr2ogr`) rather than an external process, but if you really want to use an external process, don't use `os.system`, use `subprocess.*` e.g [`subprocess.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) which handles all the commandline argument formatting for you, you just pass in a list of arguments.

Comment: @user2856 


I also tried `subprocess.run(command.format(outfile=fout, infile='points.shp', my_id=ii, name='county'), shell=True)` for my first example (that worked fine with os) and received `Warning 6: creation option 'NameField' is not formatted with the key=value format    ERROR 1: Couldn't fetch requested layer '='!` and it just creates an empty KML

Comment: @user2856 I tried `gdal.VectorTranslate` but ran into some errors; I thought it was worthwhile as its [own question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/404338/how-to-replicate-ogr2ogr-operation-with-gdal-vector-translate)

Comment: Deleted my answer and copied to your other question :) With subprocess.run, you pass a *list* of arguemnts not a command string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to use [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module):

```
import subprocess
import numpy as np
import pathlib


## example dummy ids
id1 = np.linspace(start=1, stop=1, num=1, endpoint=True, dtype=int)
id2 = np.linspace(start=1, stop=1, num=1, endpoint=True, dtype=int)

infile = '/tmp/points.shp'
inlayer = pathlib.Path(infile).stem
outpath = pathlib.Path("/tmp").resolve()
name_field = 'county'

for ii in id1:
    for jj in id2:
        fout = str(outpath / f'test{ii}_{jj}.kml')

        result = subprocess.run(
            [
                "ogr2ogr",
                "-f", "KML",
                "-where", f'ID_1 = {ii} AND ID_2 = {jj}',
                '-dsco', f'NameField={name_field}',
                fout, infile, inlayer
            ],
            capture_output=True,
            check=True)

        print(result.stdout, result.stderr)
```

Note:

- I've changed your `-sql` argument clause to a simpler `-where` argument
- I used `f'string {variable}'` aka "f strings" for a cleaner syntax
- You pass `subprocess.run` a list of arguments, not a full command string and let it handle generating the correct (properly quoted etc) command

Comment: thanks, this is a really nice and clean explanation-- and it looks like it shuld work, but I receive `TypeError: argument of type 'WindowsPath' is not iterable`. The error pops on `check=True`; then if I remove that line, error is on `capture_output=True`; and so on, removing various parts of the string. It looks like [this might be a bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue41649), where you able to run it successfully with `Path`?

Comment: That code works me as-is and if I use pathlib.Paths, but I'm using Linux, so as you're using Windows make sure you convert pathlib Paths to strings when passing to subprocess.