# Replicating ogr2ogr operation with GDAL vector translate

Tags: python, gdal, vector, ogr2ogr

Following a comment on [Error using SQL statement in ogr2ogr with Python string formatter](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/404333/error-using-sql-statement-in-ogr2ogr-with-python-string-formatter), I am trying to use  `gdal.VectorTranslate()` instead of `ogr2ogr`, but I keep receiving an error.

Using Windows, Python 3.7, and GDAL 3.3.1.

The following `ogr2ogr` approach works fine.

```py
import os
import numpy as np
import pathlib

## example dummy ids
id1 = np.linspace(start=1, stop=5, num=5, endpoint=True, dtype=int)
id2 = np.linspace(start=301, stop=302, num=2, endpoint=True, dtype=int)

outpath = pathlib.Path("working").resolve()
for ii in id1:
    command = (
        ' ogr2ogr -f "KML" "{outfile}" "{infile}" '
        ' -where "ID_1 = {my_id}" '
        ' -dsco NameField = "{name}" '
    )
    fout = 'test' + str(ii) + '.kml'
    fout = outpath / fout
    os.system(command.format(outfile=fout, infile='points.shp', my_id=ii, name='county'))
```

But trying `gdal.VectorTranslate()` based on the documentation for VectorTranslate and VectorTranslateOptions [here](https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html) throws the error as shown. I want to try this approach to see if it passes SQL statements easier than the `-sql` option in `ogr2ogr`.

```
for ii in id1:
    command = (
        ' ogr2ogr -f "KML" "{outfile}" "{infile}" '
        ' -where "ID_1 = {my_id}" '
        ' -dsco NameField = "{name}" '
    )
    fout = 'test' + str(ii) + '.kml'
    fout = outpath / fout
    args = gdal.VectorTranslateOptions(
        format="KML",
        SQLStatement=command.format(outfile=fout, infile='points.shp', my_id=ii, name='county')
    )
    gdal.VectorTranslate(
        destNameOrDestDS=fout,
        srcDS=shpecs,
        options=args
    )
```

Error:

```
C:\Users\name\anaconda3\envs\myenv\python.exe "D:/Documents/test.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
D:\Documents\points
  File "D:/Documents/test.py", line 51, in <module>
    options=args
D:\Documents\working
  File "C:\Users\name\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal.py", line 857, in VectorTranslate
    return wrapper_GDALVectorTranslateDestDS(destNameOrDestDS, srcDS, opts, callback, callback_data)
  File "C:\Users\name\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal.py", line 4625, in wrapper_GDALVectorTranslateDestDS
    return _gdal.wrapper_GDALVectorTranslateDestDS(*args)
TypeError: in method 'wrapper_GDALVectorTranslateDestDS', argument 1 of type 'GDALDatasetShadow *'
```

I receive the same error if I pass the options directly into VectorTranslate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's how to use `gdal.VectorTranslate`, note that some `ogr2ogr` options map to slightly different [arguments](https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.gdal.html#osgeo.gdal.VectorTranslateOptions), but they should be easily figured out:

```
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np
import pathlib

gdal.UseExceptions()

## example dummy ids
id1 = np.linspace(start=1, stop=1, num=1, endpoint=True, dtype=int)
id2 = np.linspace(start=1, stop=1, num=1, endpoint=True, dtype=int)

infile = '/tmp/points.shp'
inlayer = pathlib.Path(infile).stem
outpath = pathlib.Path("/tmp").resolve()
name_field = 'county'

for ii in id1:
    for jj in id2:
        fout = str(outpath / f'test{ii}_{jj}.kml')

        ds = gdal.VectorTranslate(
            fout, infile,
            # SQLStatement=f'SELECT * from {inlayer} WHERE ID_1 = {ii} AND ID_2 = {jj}',
            where=f'ID_1 = {ii} AND ID_2 = {jj}',
            datasetCreationOptions=[f'NameField={name_field}'],
            layers=[inlayer],
            format='KML'
        )
```

Note:

- I've changed your `-sql` argument clause to a simpler `-where` argument
- I used `f'string {variable}'` aka "f strings" for a cleaner syntax

Comment: Thanks, another great explanation! I receive an error on the `format='KML'` line: `File "C:\Users\name\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal.py", line 855, in VectorTranslate
    return wrapper_GDALVectorTranslateDestName(destNameOrDestDS, srcDS, opts, callback, callback_data)
  File "C:\Users\name\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal.py", line 4629, in wrapper_GDALVectorTranslateDestName
    return _gdal.wrapper_GDALVectorTranslateDestName(*args)
TypeError: in method 'wrapper_GDALVectorTranslateDestName', argument 2 of type 'GDALDatasetShadow *'`

Comment: Works for me as is because I don't pass any pathlib.Paths to gdal. Make sure the paths are strings not pathlib.Paths.  You can work with pathlib, just make sure every path is a string at the end when passing to gdal.

Comment: That was the problem, thanks for your help!